# How to store factorials?

Tags: integers, encoding-scheme, storage

Can someone help me to store the factorial of large numbers such as 100! efficiently?

UPDATE: obviously, storing the argument rather than the factorial digits themselves achieves a significant saving. The true challenge is to find a data compression scheme that achieves a significant compression ratio, but with a lighter computational complexity than recomputing the factorial(s) from the argument.

More precisely, can you design an algorithm to produce all decimal digits of $n!$, for $n\le N$, using $o(N\log N!)$ storage and small computational cost, such as the lower bound $O(\log n!)$.

Comment: @DennisMeng Anything language-specific is off-topic here; plenty of languages have no native support for very large numbers so perhaps the question is about the data structures and algorithms that underly "bignum" libraries.

Comment: @Harpreet Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange! If you want something C-specific, this is a programming question, which is off-topic here but might be on-topic at [SO]. Are you looking for C specifics or general techniques for handling very large numbers. Please edit your question (there's a link just below it) to make it more precise.

Comment: @Harpreet It's 158 digits. You could store the decimal version as text in an SMS message so what's the issue?

Comment: That, or just store "100!" as string. What are your exact requirements? (cc @DavidRicherby)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Good to know. I was just trying to get OP to narrow down the scope of what he's asking, since the question as is seems really broad.

Comment: The most efficient way is to store the generation algorithm rather than the numbers themselves. Even if written with arbitrary precision arithmetic, the code will cost a few thousand characters, and will use O(1) space. This is to be traded with the storage of factorials for different values of the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate 100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000. You can store this in any way you want: as `100!`, as the ASCII string `93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000`, as a Unicode string, or in binary in any number of formats. It all depends on what you want to do with the value. If you want to display the value on screen as a decimal, you might as well store the decimal string. If you want to do arithmetic, then you should be using a library for dealing with "big numbers" such as GMP, and in this case the library will provide its own means for storing numbers. If you're just interested in storing the expression 100!, and intend to use it in a computer algebra software (CAS), you might as well store it as just `100!`.